# Create and import data into postgresql returns error (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column "x" of relation "x" does not exist in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

I am trying to create a database in Postgres and insert data into it through sqlalchemy in Python.

Data: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/brllrb/uber-and-lyft-dataset-boston-ma

```
#connect to Postgres database
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
df = pd.read_csv("rideshare_kaggle.csv")
conn_url = 'postgresql://postgres:xxx@localhost/db1'
engine = create_engine(conn_url)
connection = engine.connect()

#create table
temperature_tb = """ 
        CREATE TABLE temperature(
            temperature_id                integer,
            apparentTemperature_id        integer,
            temperature                   numeric(4,2),
            temperatureHigh               numeric(4,2),
            temperatureHighTime           char(10),
            temperatureLow                numeric(4,2),
            temperatureLowTime            char(10),
            temperatureMin                numeric(4,2),
            temperatureMinTime            char(10),
            temperatureMax                numeric(4,2),
            temperatureMaxTime            char(10),
            PRIMARY KEY (temperature_id),
            FOREIGN KEY (apparentTemperature_id) REFERENCES apparentTemperature
        )
        """
connection.execute(temperature_tb)

#extract data to insert into table
temp_col = ["temperature", "temperatureHigh", "temperatureHighTime", "temperatureLow", "temperatureLowTime", "temperatureMin", "temperatureMinTime", "temperatureMax", "temperatureMaxTime"]
atemp_col = ["apparentTemperature", "apparentTemperatureHigh", "apparentTemperatureHighTime", "apparentTemperatureLow", "apparentTemperatureLowTime", "apparentTemperatureMin", "apparentTemperatureMinTime", "apparentTemperatureMax", "apparentTemperatureMaxTime"]
temp_df = df[temp_col + atemp_col]
temperature_df = temp_df.merge(apparentTemperature_df, on = atemp_col, how = 'inner').drop(temp_df[atemp_col], axis = 1).drop_duplicates(ignore_index = True)
temperature_df.insert(0, "temperature_id", range(1, 1 + len(temperature_df)))

#insert into table
temperature_df.to_sql(name='temperature', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

And I got the following error:

> ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column
> "temperatureHigh" of relation "temperature" does not exist LINE 1:
> ...RT INTO temperature (temperature_id, temperature, "temperatu...

Despite the table's column name being exactly the same as the column name in the data frame. I have tried to make all column names lowercase which solves the issue for this table, but it makes other tables have the same error, where column names are exactly the same but return this error.

Comment: The problem is that the table column names are not exactly the same as the data frame column names.  See [Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) for the complete explanation.  The short explanation is you need to double quote upper/mixed case identifiers e.g. `CREATE TABLE temperature( ..."temperatureHigh" ..)`.

Comment: OMG Thank you so much. Adding a double quote to all solved the problem.